# Include logo in order update email

Tags: php, opencart, e-commerce

When a purchase is made, an email goes out notifying the customer of the purchase details and processing status. This email automatically includes the company logo at the top. When I update the order history and select Notify Customer the email that goes out does not include the logo. How can I set the logo to go with that update email?
OC3

Comment: Copy the email code from the first email?

Comment: did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Edit this controller file:

```
catalog\controller\mail\order.php
```

Find:

```
public function edit($order_info, $order_status_id, $comment) {
```

Add after:

```
$data['logo'] = $order_info['store_url'] . 'image/' . $this->config->get('config_logo');
$data['store_name'] = $order_info['store_name'];
$data['store_url'] = $order_info['store_url'];
```

Find:

```
$mail->setText($this->load->view('mail/order_edit', $data));
```

Change to:

```
$mail->setHtml($this->load->view('mail/order_edit', $data));
```

Edit this view file:

```
catalog\view\theme\default(or your theme)\template\mail\order_edit.twig
```

Add this, where you want to show the logo:

```
<div style="width: 680px;"><a href="{{ store_url }}" title="{{ store_name }}"><img src="{{ logo }}" alt="{{ store_name }}" style="margin-bottom: 20px; border: none;" /></a></div>
```

Note that since we changed the email format from text to html, we need to arrange the rest of the file as well as the logo.
For example this:

```
{{ text_order_id }} {{ order_id }}
```

should be:

```
<div style="width: 680px;">{{ text_order_id }} {{ order_id }}</div>
```